# How to Determine the tables are currently in use or removeable

Tags: sql

Any one,

can please guide me the way to find via sql statement.
that i want to delete those tables which are not currently in use by any application/user.
and are removeable.

thank you!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted on this, though you could have made your question more specific and provided more information about your DBMS in your original post...or perhaps spent a little more time with Google.

SQL Server does provide dynamic management views that can help you determine which tables are in use. That's not the case for all DBMSes, but SQL Server has a very rich set of statistics to help you keep an eye on database usage.

Take a look at this blog entry: http://www.sqlfingers.com/2014/02/find-unused-tables-in-sql-server.html. The `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` DMV contains information on index usage. By selecting your table entries in `sys.objects` and joining that against `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` on `object_id`, you can tell which tables have indexes that have been used since the last DB restart. That will give you some idea of which tables are "in use," though you should consider how frequently you restart your DB and how many infrequently-used features you have in your application before you consider a table "unused."